# not able to find the specific a's href using jquery

Tags: jquery

i am working on some list items and on readicon class click i am not able to capture the href  value of a with class bookpath. in this case (google.com)
here is the code

```
<li >
  <div class="overlay">
  <span id="Title">Yeah Dude</span>
  <img class="readIcon" src="images/read.png" />
  </div>
 <a class="bookPath" href="http://www.google.com"><img src="images/bookCovers/asp.net4.5.jpg"  alt="book" /></a></li>
```

i tried this code but it returns undefined.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
$(".overlay .readIcon").click(function () {
    //    $(this).('href', 'index.html');
    var bookPath = $(this).parents('li').closest('a').href;
    alert(bookPath);


});});
```

thanks a lot.

Comment: `var bookPath = $(this).parents('li').closest('a')[0].href;`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your query to this:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(".overlay .readIcon").click(function () {
        var bookPath = $(this).parents('li').children('a').attr('href');
        alert(bookPath);
    });
});
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Lbr4z/

Comment: what i did wrong was i went for closest rather than sibling with wrong href attribute.. thanks a lot for lovely answer.

Answer (score 0):

Get the href atttribute value. use `closest` to get outer li and use `find` to get the anchor

```
var bookPath = $(this).closest('li').find('a').attr("href");
```

Jsfiddle sample : http://jsfiddle.net/4QGHS/5/

Also when doing jQuery selectors, **try to be more specific as you can**. `find('a')` will return all anchor tags. So you better use the ***classname*** which you have for elements you are looking for. Try to give a class to your `li` element as well.

```
<li class='bookItem'>
  <div class="overlay">
  // your other html goes here 
   <img class="readIcon" src="someImage.jog" /> 
  </div>
  <a class="bookPath" href="http://www.google.com"></a>
</li>
```

now your javascript will be

```
$(function(){

 $(".overlay .readIcon").click(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();  //prevent as needed.
    var bookPath = $(this).closest('li.bookItem').
                                            find('a.bookPath').attr("href");
    alert(bookPath);
 });

});
```

Jsfiddle sample http://jsfiddle.net/4QGHS/9/

Comment: Doesn't `.closest()` travels up the DOM tree? It's similar to `.parents`. I think it should be: $(this).closest('li').find('a').attr("href")

Comment: @RustyJeans: closest travels up the DOM tree until it finds a match for the supplied selector. parents travels up to DOM tree and add matched item to a temp collection and then do a filter. I think closest is the suitable thing to use here.

Comment: @Shyju  I agree, looks like you updated your answer right when I was posting my comment.

Comment: @Rick Are you clicking on the image, or the link?

Comment: @RickCalder: I tested it in chrome and firefox (windows) and works fine.

Comment: Yeah my mistake Shyju, Rusty was right I misread it and was clicking the link.

Answer (score 0):

Use `$(selector).attr("href");` :)

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways to do this and this is one.

```
 $(document).ready(function () {

    $(".overlay .readIcon").click(function () {
        //    $(this).('href', 'index.html');
        var bookPath = $(this).parent().parent().find("a.bookPath").attr("href");
        alert(bookPath);


    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try with `.siblings()`

```
var bookPath = $(this).parent().siblings('a').attr('href');
```

Try with `.find()`

```
var bookPath = $(this).closest('li').find('a').attr('href');
```

if you want to be more specific then:

```
var bookPath = $(this).closest('li').find('a.bookPath').attr('href');
```